# Display JSON Array in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, local-storage

I have a JSON array in `localstorage`. I want to retrieve this array, and display the values.
The storage key is `_myobject`, and the value is

```
[{"64508":"12:12:2"},{"5292":"12:17:34"}]
```

What I want is to know how I can use JavaScript/jQuery to display/print the values in the following format:

```
Number: 64508 - Time:  12:12:2
Number: 5292 - Time: 12:17:34
```

Could somebody please direct me on how I could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert from your array into the string.  Try something like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("_myobject"));
obj.map(function(item) { 
     // (really just the first key)
     for (var key in item) 
         return "Number: " + key + " - Time: " + item[key]; 
}).join(" ");
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7wW2V/1/)

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly after I worked with the fiddle link. I really appreciate your time.